# Android: Percentage in gradient drawable?

Tags: android, css, drawable, gradient

I wanted some effect like CSS gradient

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f0b7a1), color-stop(50%,#8c3310), color-stop(51%,#752201), color-stop(100%,#bf6e4e));
```

my android xml drawable code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/transparent"
        android:centerColor="#33b5e5"
        android:endColor="@color/transparent"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

so what i want to achieve is adding percentage like this:

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/transparent"
    android:25%="#09c"
    android:centerColor="#33b5e5"
    android:75%="#09c"
    android:endColor="@color/transparent"
    android:angle="90"/>
```

any method can i do this?

Comment: Did you finally found a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do it with percentages, but you can achieve the outcome using overlapping gradients.

You'll need to fiddle a bit with the `scaleY` and colours to make it match your example, but the approach should be straightforward. You're layering multiple transparent -> colour -> transparent gradients over each other with vertical offsets.

Here's an example of it in action, I've also added a blank white base layer:
[image: overlapping android gradients]

And here's the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item><shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape></item>

    <item><shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
            android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerY="0.4"
            />
    </shape></item>

    <item><shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerY="0.4"
            />
    </shape></item>

    <item><shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerY="0.7"
            />
    </shape></item>

    <item><shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            />
    </shape></item>
</layer-list>
```